# Give an example such that $(x_ny_n)$ converges but $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ diverges.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> Give an example of sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(x_ny_n)$ converges but $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ diverges.

My answer: Let $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n=(-1)^n$. Then, $x_ny_n=(-1)^n(-1)^n=(-1)^{2n}$. So, $(-1)^{2n}$ convergence to $1$ and $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ diverges.

**Can you check my answer?**

Comment: Your example looks fine to me; however, you may want to prove (if you haven't already) that $\left((-1)^n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is divergent and $(1)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent (the latter is trivial).

Comment: Looks good to me! You could have $x_n$ and $y_n$ alternate between 0 and 1, but offset so they multiply to 0.

Comment: Thanks for comments.

Comment: Your answer is not only correct, but it is probably one of the easiest and most forward of all examples that one can come up with. Nice. +1

Answer (score 1):

We can take
$$a_n=(2+(-1)^n) $$
$$b_n=(2-(-1)^n) $$
$$a_nb_n=3$$

or
$$a_n=\sin (n) \;\;,\; \;b_n=\frac {1}{\sin (n)} $$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. $$ a_n = sin(n+1)$$ and $$b_n = csc (n+1)$$ where $  {a_n}{b_n}$ converges to $1$ while both  $ a_n$  and $ b_n$ diverge.

Comment: The question asks about $a_n b_n$